# How to receive remote push notifications in android using GCM in Delphi 10

Tags: http, delphi, google-cloud-messaging, delphi-10-seattle

i am trying to send and receive remote push notifications using GCM services, when i had Delphi xe7 this method in the answer 2 in this question was working [[Google Cloud Messaging in Delphi XE5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838485/google-cloud-messaging-in-delphi-xe5/21444622#21444622]), but in Seattle it dosent, i get java errors, however, i've followed the answer in this question, and managed to get the device Token id, but i cant dont receive the notification when i send it to my mobile phone, this is the code to send :

```
const
  sendUrl = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
var
  Params: TStringList;
  AuthHeader: STring;
  idHTTP: TIDHTTP;
  SSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
 idHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(nil);
try
 SslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
 idHTTP.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
 idHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];
 Params := TStringList.Create;
try
  Params.Add('registration_id='+ Memo1.Lines.Text);
  Params.Values['data.message'] := Edit1.Text;
  idHTTP.Request.Host := sendUrl;
  AuthHeader := 'Authorization: key=' + MyServerKey;
  idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add(AuthHeader);
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
  idHTTP.Post(sendUrl, Params);
finally
  Params.Free;
end;
finally
 FreeAndNil(idHTTP);
end;
```

Added `<service android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMIntentService" />` in my AndroidManifest.template.xml and checked receive remote push notifications in Entitlement List.

Comment: Which are the errors?

Comment: I'm getting a message about a Service tag missing the attribute "name" in the Manifest template @RBA

Comment: Do you have the full eror message?

Comment: @mjn42 solved it, combine datamoudle source and formMain source in a single unit.